# How to Get Github Issues to Linkify a Commit Hash from a Different Repository at Same Organization

Tags: github

If one creates a new GitHub repository, makes a commit with a hash, say, 56a18b4a829473e036f43c14611ab8a7022c500b, then creates an issue in that repository and mentions the hash in the issue comment, GitHub will shorten and linkify the hash.

However, if one includes a hash from a commit in a different repository within the same organization, GitHub does not linkify.

Is it possible to have GitHub Issues automatically linkify these extra-repo hashes?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/autolinked-references-and-urls/#commit-shas

Answer (score 0):

If you just include the full URL of the commit in REPO B in the issue for REPO A, github will link the two automatically. You just can't use the short version. It will look like `org/repo@abc123`